# Looking for Autocompletion field to replace select menu

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking to replace my select menu for my products inside of my form and wanted to know if anyone can list choices or alternatives.

This is my select menu:

```
<%= select("price", "product_id", Product.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]) %>
```

I want an autocomplete field to replace it instead. These are the choices so far:

[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

[Jquery TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

OK, so far we have two, anymore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a client-side solution, [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is a very good jQuery plugin. It'll transform any select field into an drop-down with autocomplete.

Note that Chosen is actually disabled on iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android mobile devices, so if your site needs to support mobile, Chosen is not a valid option.

Comment: + 1 for Chosen. I'm currently working with this plugin and it's just elegant and simple.

Comment: This post is quite old so worth saying to newcomers - Chosen works great on my desktop, viewing my site on mobile, Chosen doesn't work at all.

Comment: It's true, the lack of support for mobile is documented in their FAQ section. I've edited the post to reflect that, though, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this plugin should more than cover your needs.

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete